# How to dynamically call the webservices from .NET Core

Tags: web-services, wcf, asp.net-core

Currently I am consuming some webservices with multiple endpoints in .NET with the help of WCF Webservices reference provider tool. If there are any changes in webservices then I have to update or delete and reattach, then again will have to build to get the DLL and put in to deployment server.

This is very time consuming. Are there any alternate options?

Answer (score 0):

At first, the WCF created by some complex bindings, authentication security may not work well with NetCore,such as Wshttpbinding. Generally, basichttpbinding is supported by the Core-based client.
With the interface, address and other service information unchanged, we can call the service dynamically through the channel factory, No matter how the server changes the implementation of the service. It does not affect the client’s invocation.
Here is an example.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://10.157.13.69:1500");
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        ChannelFactory<ICalculator> factory = new ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(binding,new EndpointAddress(uri));
        ICalculator service = factory.CreateChannel();
        try
        {
            var result = service.Add(34.32, 2.34);
            Console.WriteLine(result);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculator
{
    [OperationContract]
    double Add(double a, double b);
}
```

Here is a related document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.